# Gradle apply from no access to parent properties

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have build grade file where I externalize some docker related operations.

My build.gradle file defines a docker image name.

**build.gradle:**

```
def docker = [
        imageName: "myOrg/$rootProject.name:$version",
]

apply from: 'build-config/docker.gradle'
```

The applied script contains task that access the **docker.imageName** variable.

**docker.gradle**

```
...
task buildImage(group: "Docker", dependsOn: createDockerfile, type:Exec) {
    executable "docker"
    args 'build','-t',docker.imageName,'build'
}
```

Now I get the error  **`Could not find property 'docker' on task ':buildImage'.`**

How could I use the variables defined in my build.gradle in the applied frome gradle script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `def` with `ext.` in the declaration of `docker` variable in `build.gradle`, as follows:

```
ext.docker = [
    imageName: "myOrg/$rootProject.name:$version",
]

apply from: 'build-config/docker.gradle'
```

Basically the `ext` namespace is used to define project level custom properties, which will then be accessible to the applied script `docker.gradle` which is also falling under the project's scope.

With `def` alone, the property visibility is restricted to the script file only.